# Canonical url htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, friendly-url, canonical-link

I am trying to achieve certain thing via htaccess file.
I would like this

http://mypage.com/e-store/561/
http://mypage.com/e-store/562/

to look like this

http://mypage.com/tv-screens
http://mypage.com/computers

I have read that it is possible via htaccess with rewrite urls. But I cant manage to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this is .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ ?url=$1 [L]
```

And add in your code output pages as:

```
http://mypage.com/?url=tv-screens
```

Where on the parameter URL the necessary page is displayed.

This link doesn't display page screen name:

```
http://mypage.com/e-store/561/
```

Comment: Okay, I added the first line to htaccess.
but I have trouble with adding code to output pages. Is this the href in <a> or I have to look somewhere else?

Comment: @osiic21 No, you must create a code that, when requested http://mypage.com/?url=tv-screens, will output the page you need. That is, the name of future URL should already be in query parameter.

Comment: This link http://mypage.com/e-store/561/ can only be used for conversion http://mypage.com/561